# How expensive is gluing binaries (list_to_binary)?

Tags: erlang, binary, list

One process listen to server on async socket and on each message {tcp, Socket, Bin} takes it's buffer and:

```
Data = list_to_binary([Buffer, Bin]),
    {next_state, 'READY', State#state{buffer = Data}}.
```

On some events it flushes buffer:

```
'READY'({flush}, #state{buffer = Buffer} = State) ->
    {reply, {Buffer}, 'READY', State#state{buffer = <<>>}}.
```

Is it expensive? Maybe better just to make a list and make list_to_binary(lists:reverse()) once on flush?

Comment: This is a question better answered by a benchmark than theorizing about the current implementation.

Comment: Does your setup require that on flush the buffer is returned as one binary? Isn't the user able to handle the buffer in 'chunks', or handle iodata() format ?

Answer (score 2):

Your first method appears to be *much* slower than your second method (by a factor of about 3000 on my platform):

```
-module(test).
-export([test/0, performance_test/4]).

-define(ITERATIONS, 100000).
-define(NEW_DATA, <<1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10>>).

accumulate_1(AccumulatedData, NewData) ->
  list_to_binary([AccumulatedData, NewData]).

extract_1(AccumulatedData) ->
  AccumulatedData.

accumulate_2(AccumulatedData, NewData) ->
  [NewData | AccumulatedData].

extract_2(AccumulatedData) ->
  list_to_binary(lists:reverse(AccumulatedData)).

performance_test(AccumulateFun, ExtractFun) ->
  {Time, _Result} = timer:tc(test, performance_test, [AccumulateFun, ExtractFun, [], ?ITERATIONS]),
  io:format("Test run: ~p microseconds~n", [Time]).

performance_test(_AccumulateFun, ExtractFun, AccumulatedData, _MoreIterations = 0) ->
  ExtractFun(AccumulatedData);

performance_test(AccumulateFun, ExtractFun, AccumulatedData, MoreIterations) ->
  NewAccumulatedData = AccumulateFun(AccumulatedData, ?NEW_DATA),
  performance_test(AccumulateFun, ExtractFun, NewAccumulatedData, MoreIterations - 1).

test() ->
  performance_test(fun accumulate_1/2, fun extract_1/1),
  performance_test(fun accumulate_2/2, fun extract_2/1),
  ok.
```

Output:

```
7> test:test().
Test run: 57204314 microseconds
Test run: 18996 microseconds
```

Comment: Good that you benchmarked it. :)  The benchmark is extreme in that you build a 1 million byte binary in blocks of 10 bytes. Copying time grows with binary size. Building a hundred binaries 10 kb each, in ten byte increments, should be faster. Also, the list accumulating one adds the same literal small binary to the list, decreasing pressure on the GC, and has an advantage because of that.

Answer (score 2):

In current releases, the handling of binaries by the emulator has been significant improved,
so now you could also take the simpler path and generate the binary chunk by chunk:

buffer = `#state{buffer = <<Buffer/binary, Bin/binary>>}`.

I didn't test it against the other approach, but shouldn't be bad. 
Performance between different implementations will also likely depends on how many times you are performing this on the same buffer and how big each chunk is.